# How to find the first ancestor (of element table) without using multiple parent() call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this structure:

```
table > thead > tr > th > span
```

I know $self is the span i clicked and that I can get the table with 4 parent()
's but how can I do it more smootly?

It's like find() just up in the DOM, is that what closest() is for?

```
var $table = $self.parent().parent().parent().parent();
```

Comment: $self.parents("table:first"); ?

Comment: Yes, you would use `.closest()`... `$self.closest('table')`.

Comment: Here the docs http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.closest()` function. Example:

```
var $span = $('#mySpan');
var $span_table = $span.closest('table');
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see it works. My suggestion with parents(table:first) also works. (I found it in releated question to mine.) What would you recommend using? :)

Comment: Closest is faster. That is recommended.

Comment: As long as your span element will never *contain* a table, personally I'd stick with `.closest()`

Comment: Closest is the way to go.

Comment: Your jQuery wrap of $span in the second like is redundant tought I think.

Comment: @Joseph, `span`s should not contain `table`s per the spec, but many implementations allow it.  Regardless, it wouldn't matter if it *did* contain a table, because `closest` doesn't search the element's children.